# How do you customize the RSS feeds in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, rss, moss

In the early days of SharePoint 2007 beta, I've come across the ability to customize the template used to emit the RSS feeds from lists.  I can't find it again.  Anybody know where it is?

Comment: Do you mean the xml structure itself or just the columns being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found it, based on [a subtle hint from Jan Tielens](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2006/06/07/YASR_3A00_-RSS-In-SharePoint-2007.aspx).  It's on the Settings page for the list, under Communications -> RSS settings.
/_layouts/listsyndication.aspx?List=*<list id>*

I could have sworn there was more, like an actual template file you could customize.

Answer (score 1):

I my search, also came across [*Customize RSS for the Content Query Web Part*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608445.aspx)

"After you customize the Content Query Web Part to display the fields and content you want, you can set up the Web Part to emit a Really Simple Syndication (RSS) feed of that content."